# WordPress WooCommerce product attribute set_visible false via functions.php is not stored permanently

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

### Problem

*I want to hide all product attributes used for variation purpose in the 'Additional information' section of the product detail page.*

[image]

### Background

I use WordPress 5.5.1 with WooCommerce 4.6.1. I have a lot of products in my WooCommerce shop and nearly all of them have several custom product attributes. Those attributes are used for variations so customers can select e.g. gender and color of a product.

Unfortunately, most of those attributes are set to be visible in the frontend which does not make any sense since those attributes are already used for variation select boxes. **Therefore, I want to hide all of those attributes used for variation purpose in the 'Additional information' section of the product detail page.**

### Possible solutions

#### Workaround

I found a workaround here https://datafeedrapi.helpscoutdocs.com/article/206-hide-specific-attributes-from-the-additional-information-tab. However, I want to make those changes permanent (in DB).

#### My current solution which does save visibility changes to DB

```php
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_woocommerce_hide_product_attributes_in_descr' );  

    function custom_woocommerce_hide_product_attributes_in_descr() {
        $args = array(
            'status' => 'publish',
            'type' => 'variable',
            'limit' => -1,
            'sku' => 'mySKU',
        );
        $products = wc_get_products( $args );
    
        foreach ( $products as &$product ){
            if ($product->has_attributes()) {
                $currentProdAttributes = $product->get_attributes();

                foreach ($currentProdAttributes as &$productAttribute ) {
                    $productAttribute->set_visible( false );
                }
                unset( $productAttribute );
    
                $product->set_attributes($currentProdAttributes);
                $id = $product->save();
                error_log(wc_get_product($id));
            }
        }
        unset( $product );
    }
```

The main problem is that `$id = $product->save();` does not save the changes to database. Did I forget something here?